# PHP button stops working when if / elseif is triggered

Tags: php, jquery, button, if-statement

I am trying to echo a button to get the songs from the default div into the playlist:

```
    <?php
        include('dbcon.php');
            if(isset($_REQUEST['all']) && $_REQUEST['all'] != ''){
                    //===============================Button "ALL"====================================
                    unset($_REQUEST['kw']);
                    unset($_REQUEST['genre']);

                    $query = "select * from music";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
                    echo "<ul>";
                    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )){
                        echo '<li><button type="button" class="addtoplaylist" action="../js/addtoplaylist.js">Add to playlist!</button> '.$info['artist'].' - '.$info['title'].' ('.$info['album'].') '.'<hr /></li>';
                    };
                    echo "</ul>";
                }elseif (isset($_REQUEST['kw']) && $_REQUEST['kw'] != ''){
                    //============================= Search for music ================================
                    $kws = $_REQUEST['kw'];
                    $kws = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $kws);

                    $query = "select * from music where title like '%".$kws."%' or artist like '%".$kws."%'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error($link));
                    echo "<ul>";
                    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )){
                        echo '<li><button type="button" class="addtoplaylist" action="../js/addtoplaylist.js">Add to playlist!</button> '.$info['artist'].' - '.$info['title'].' ('.$info['album'].') '.'<hr /></li>';
                    };
                    echo "</ul>";
                }elseif(isset($_REQUEST['genre']) && $_REQUEST['genre'] != ''){
                    //=====================================Browse By Genre ===========================================
                    $genre = $_REQUEST['genre'];
                    $genre = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $genre);
                    $gquery = "select music_id from musicgenre where genre_id = '$genre'";
                    $results = mysqli_query($link, $gquery) or die (mysqli_error($link));
                    $music=array();
                    while($id_result = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
                        $music[] = $id_result['music_id'];
                    };
                    foreach($music as $song){
                        $query = "select * from music where music_id = '$song'";
                        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error());;
                        echo "<ul>";
                        while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo '<li><button type="button" class="addtoplaylist" action="../js/addtoplaylist.js">Add to playlist!</button> '.$info['artist'].' - '.$info['title'].' ('.$info['album'].') '.'<hr /></li>';
                        };
                        echo "</ul>";
                    };
                }else{
                // ================================ Default =========================================

                    $query = "select * from music";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
                    echo "<ul>";
                    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )){
                        echo '<li><button type="button" class="addtoplaylist" action="../js/addtoplaylist.js">Add to playlist!</button> '.$info['artist'].' - '.$info['title'].' ('.$info['album'].') '.'<hr /></li>';
                    };
                    echo "</ul>";
            };

?>
```

and here is the jquery file witch actually does that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addtoplaylist").click(function(){
        var $value = $(this);
        var $container = $value.parent();
        $container.appendTo("#playlist");
        $value.remove();

    })
})
```

So here's the thing. When i first load the page (like writing the url and press enter) everything works fine, all the buttons and stuff, but as soon as i click on a category or any other thing that triggers the if/elseif/else statement my buttons stop working.

Can someone please help me understand what the problem may be? I had this problem before on my pagination end ended up removing the entire code because i can't seem to find an answer. In the pagination code my button disappeared when i clicked on anything that triggered the switch. I get all the results like it should, so that part works well, but this button stuff drives me crazy. I tried everything i could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that my results were ajax generated so i just had to copy the jquery part and add it to my ajax in the success function.

Answer (score 0):

you're using the switch statement in wrong way, use a if-elseif statement:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['all']) && $_REQUEST['all'] != '') {
    //Stuff
} elseif (isset($_REQUEST['kw']) && $_REQUEST['kw'] != '') {
    //Stuff
} elseif ....
```

the switch statement check if a variable equals a value:

```
$name = 'Alberto';
switch($name) {
  case 'Alberto':
     //We're here now
     break;
  case 'John':
     //Nothing to do here for the moment
     break;
  default:
     //Stuff for every values of $name that are different from 'Alberto' or 'John'
 }
```

so you need to change your code logic to use it

Comment: i tried that as well, it was my first choice but the same thing happens.

Comment: where do you implement the @playlist div?

Comment: the playlist div is on the same page, and like i said, if it's on default, before i click anything to trigger the switch (or the if/elseif) statement it works as it should.

Comment: i added the html part of this as well :)